# How to get current file path if launched from a shortcut in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shortcut, shortcut-file

I'm running **python 3.9** on **Windows 10**.

I want to know **if my script was launched from a shortcut file**,
and if it is this I want to know **how to get the current full path of that shortcut**

- Thank you in advance

Comment: Couldn't you just check if the file has extension `.lnk`?

Answer (score 0):

Call the [`GetStartupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getstartupinfow) Windows function and check for the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag.